# Spring WebFlow: What can i do with flow outcome?

Tags: spring-webflow

I'm reading Spring WebFlow documentation, but I don't understand what can i do with `outcome` value in end-state of flow. Could You show me some practical example ? I wonder how to pass outcome variable to MVC Controller or another flow, but don't know how.

```
<flow>
    <end-state id="test2">
          <output name="id" value="123" />
    </end-state>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your output variables from the parent flow (if you have called a subflow) by using currentEvent.attributes (so in your example):

```
currentEvent.attributes.id
```

See section [3.10 Calling Subflows](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#calling-subflows)

You can also get them programatically in a `FlowHandler` by implementing the `handleExecutionOutcome` method.  There is an example in the docs under the "Example FlowHandler" section of [11.4 Implementing custom FlowHandlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-config-flow-handlers).